# How to construct a linear system that has no sol

Tags: linear-algebra

Construct a linear system that has no solution. Unknown Variable counts must be more than the equation count. Is it possible an equation like this? What are needed?

Comment: x=1, x=2 (2 equations, unknown variables are x, y, z).

Comment: @Engineertryingmath To my opinion, this example does not qualify since the variables do not occur explicitely.

Comment: The simplest example is $$x+y+z=0$$ $$x+y+z=1$$ We have no solution if and only if the rank of the matrix $A$ and the rank of the matrix $A$ concatenated with $b$ (where the equation $Ax=b$ is given) do not coincide.

Comment: @Peter there is no reason to require that variables should occur explicitly. But if you want, just consider x=1 and x=2 as shorthand for 1*x+0*y+0*z=1 and 1*x+0*y+0*z=2. Note that your example is nearly the same (just more verbose) after the coordinate trafo i=x+y+z, j=x, k=y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which might be useful.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 2 & 2\\
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Mainly, the rank of the matrix is 1 which is less than the dimension of the right hand side (which is two).  Therefore, you can find a right hand side which doesn't have a solution vector $\mathbf{x}$.

I hope this helps.